# Unable to use JSON data after pushing into array with Javascript .push Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, array-push

I am not able to retrieve the values from an array after storing it in a variable outside of getJSON.

My **JSON response** is:

```
[
    {
        "Book_ID": "1",
        "Book_Name": "Computer Architecture",
        "Category": "Computers",
        "Price": "125.60"
    },
    {
        "Book_ID": "2",
        "Book_Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
        "Category": "Programming",
        "Price": "56.00"
    },
    {
        "Book_ID": "3",
        "Book_Name": "Popular Science",
        "Category": "Science",
        "Price": "210.40"
    }
]
```

**Using the jQuery $.getJson function:**

```
  var booksList = [];
  $.getJSON( "books.json", function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
     booksList.push(value);
    });
  });
```

**When I try to get the BOOK ID,**

```
console.log(booksList[0].BOOK_ID);
```

I get the following **error**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Book_ID' of undefined

**But when I log the complete array,**

```
console.log(booksList);
```

[I see this response in the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP6Y3.png)

Comment: show the code where you are doing `console.log(booksList[0].BOOK_ID);`

Comment: Also `BOOK_ID` is not same as `Book_ID`

Comment: You are probably accessing `console.log(booksList[0].BOOK_ID);` outside `getJSON` callback.

Comment: can you try with console.log(data). i need to see your data

Comment: you can simply use booksList=data no need of iteration

Comment: Notice how the two outputs are different `[]` vs `(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]`. Also notice the blue box with the `i`. The console shows you the value at the moment you expand the details, not when the value was actually logged. At that moment the response has been received.

Comment: @NegiRox Please see the attached file console.log(data). I need to access the data outside of getJSON.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes that is the case. How do I access the data of getJSON outside of the its function ?

Comment: You can pass the data as argument to another function: `$.getJSON(..., function() { ... doSomething(booksList); })`. See the duplicate.

Comment: It requires aysnc:false which is only possible with the full version of $.ajax function.  @FelixKling yes I tried that tooit works but I need to use the data in multiple functions

Comment: This works, but is the worst solution. Learn about asynchronous execution flows in JavaScript, because they are everywhere (e.g. event handlers).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your help.

Comment: you can directly assign bookList=data; and you will be able to access it outside

Answer (score 0):

```
var booksList = [];
$.getJSON( "books.json", function( data ) {
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
   booksList.push(value);
  });
});
```

`$.getJSON()` returns immediately and `$.each()` also returns immediately, while the code inside the function is still executing in a separate thread. The code after that executes immediately and so the list isnt updated when you try to get data from it and its empty thus there is an error

```
var booksList = [];
$.getJSON( "books.json", function( data ) {
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
   booksList.push(value);
   console.log(booksList[0].Book_ID);
  });
});
console.log("hi");
```

will show the updated list while `"hi"` gets printed first.